# Tweaking Plone Dexterity Container View

Tags: dexterity, grok, plone-4.x

I have a custom plone dexterity content type which is a container of other dexterity types.  I have added an additional view to recursively summarize the contents of this type.

I'm needing anonymous users to be able to navigate to the default view like normal, but then also be presented with a link to this summary view.  I do not wish to rewrite the default view from scratch, but just add a simple hyperlink to it.  I have read the [dexterity manual](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/index.html), but I cannot seem to make the leap to how to pull off something like what I'm trying to do.

Any recommendations?